# Python 3.xx - Deleting consecutive numbers/letters from a string

Tags: string, python-3.x

I actually need help evaluating what is going on with the code which I wrote.

It is meant to function like this:

```
input: remove_duple('WubbaLubbaDubDub')

output: 'WubaLubaDubDub'
```

another example:

```
input: remove_duple('aabbccdd')

output: 'abcd'
```

I am still a beginner and I would like to know both what is wrong with my code and an easier way to do it. (There are some lines in the code which were part of my efforts to visualize what was happening and debug it)

```
def remove_duple(string):
    to_test = list(string)
    print (to_test)
    icount = 0
    dcount = icount + 1
    for char in to_test:
        if to_test[icount] == to_test[dcount]:
            del to_test[dcount]
            print ('duplicate deleted')
            print (to_test)
            icount += 1
        elif to_test[icount] != to_test[dcount]:
            print ('no duplicated deleted')
            print (to_test)
            icount += 1
    print ("".join(to_test))
```

Comment: Have a look at how simple it looks [with a regex](https://ideone.com/BpT3NE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify a `list` (e.g. `del to_test[dcount]`) that you are iterating over. Your iterator will get screwed up. The appropriate way to deal with this would be to create a new `list` with only the values you want.

A fix for your code could look like:

```
In []:
def remove_duple(s):
    new_list = []
    for i in range(len(s)-1):  # one less than length to avoid IndexError
        if s[i] != s[i+1]:
            new_list.append(s[i])
    if s:                      # handle passing in an empty string
        new_list.append(s[-1]) # need to add the last character

    return "".join(new_list)   # return it (print it outside the function)

remove_duple('WubbaLubbaDubDub')

Out[]:
WubaLubaDubDub
```

As you are looking to step through the string, sliding 2 characters at a time, you can do that simply by `zip`ing the string with itself shifted one, and adding the first character if the 2 characters are not equal, e.g.:

```
In []:
import itertools as it

def remove_duple(s):
    return ''.join(x for x, y in it.zip_longest(s, s[1:]) if x != y)

remove_duple('WubbaLubbaDubDub')

Out[]:
'WubaLubaDubDub'

In []:
remove_duple('aabbccdd')

Out[]:
'abcd'
```

Note: you need `itertools.zip_longest()` or you will drop the last character. The default `fillvalue` of `None` is fine for a string.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I need some clarification on the first code you gave: 
 `if s: new_list.append(s[-1])`
You commented that it is for handling if an empty string is passed, but I tried putting spaces and giving an empty string without that line of code and the output was the same. What does this line do exactly?

Comment: If you don't have that line and pass an empty string `''` you would get an `IndexError`.